# Make an element at least the height of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

What I'd like to do is have sections (all other content inside) for a one page layout. Some of these sections don't have enough content to reach all the way to the bottom of a screen on desktop, but if I set a 'magic number' value in CSS (i.e. min-height:1000px) you'd be scrolling forever when viewing on a phone. Inversely, I don't want to cut off conent that extends past viewport height. JavaScript is definitely not my strong point, but here is my (likely god awful) attempt with Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //make sections at least as tall as the viewport
    $(window).height(function () {
        if ('section'.height <= window.height) {
            $('section').css('height', window.height);
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone know a better way? How far off (/or being stupid) am I?
Anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //make sections at least as tall as the viewport

    var $sections = $('section').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('oheight', $this.height())
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var winheight = $(window).height();
        $('section').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this), oheight = $this.data('oheight') || $this.height();
            $this.css('height', oheight <= winheight ? winheight : oheight);

            //remove this
            $this.find('.height').text(oheight <= winheight ? winheight : oheight)
        })
    }).resize()

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kMAbv/)

Comment: Use `$this.height()` instead of `$this.css('height', `

Comment: Thanks! Is that all I had wrong? And how can I have it refire if the page is resized?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS to do this? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgktx/1/)**

```
body, html, section {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't separate your styles for each views(desktop, mobile, ...)?